# COUNTIF using Table terminology

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, countif, excel-tables

I have a table called Table1, and I want to use Table terminology (for example: instead of B$2 write something that include the name of the column ("String"))

Would love to use your help. Thanks.

[image]

**Edit:**
It's not a solution to my question but I found an alternative solution using INDIRECT ADDRESS

This is a generic formula to COUNTIF to previous column:
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN()-1,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1,4)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1,4)))

[image]

Comment: INDIRECT is volatile and should be avoided to avoid overcharge, if possible. You got another options

Comment: Thanks. I have a huge table (200 columns, 10000 rows), I'm trying to make it fast as possible without threads calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected

Don't try

`=COUNTIF([String],[@String])`

Instead try

`=SUM(([String]=[@String])*(ROW([String])<=ROW([@String])))`

Comment: Notice this would return 3 in each row, and according to image posted by OP, result of formula is 1,2,3, because the range is dynamic

Comment: You're right. My bad.  I have corrected it to use an array formula.

Comment: Oh, did not think about array formulas, indeed this works!

Comment: Works! what about efficiency if compared to A$2:A2,A2 ?

Comment: I have used array formulae on tables of 100,000 entries and haven't had any issues.  That is not a guarantee but I don't think structured formulae and array formulae are slower than A1 type of references.

Comment: I know that normally table references are faster than the A1 type of references. I'll give your solution a try. cheers :)

Comment: what if instead of COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2) I would like to use a specific value like this: COUNTIF(A$2:A2,"ABC"), how would the general table formula would change?
=SUM(([String]=[@String])*(ROW([String])<=ROW([@String])))